# Sending put request to local database every second

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to build a software similar pos for a restaurant . Once order is taken it is stored in file named orderInQueue.json. in navigation i have “queued orders” tab. As we visit this all the orders that are not completed yet show under this screen. but when we switch over different tabs the time starts back from 0 . I was thinking to update “timeElapsed” in json file every second so that state is in sync with it. Or thats to much work for browser and there is a better way to implement this? Thanks in advance for your any help !

Tried to use setInterval function in useEffect to send put requests every second to update timeElapsed in json file and get requests to update state

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating the "timeElapsed" in your JSON file every second, please consider storing the order creation time. You can calculate the "timeElapsed" on the fly when displaying it by subtracting the order creation time from the current time. This approach is more efficient and won't put unnecessary load on your server.